# podman still remembers a no longer existing user

Tags: podman

This command:

```
$ podman login --get-login
```

Gives this response:

```
Error: mkdir /home/chrismurphy: permission denied
```

I have recently renamed the user `chrismurphy` to `chris`, so `/home/chrismurphy` doesn't even exist. So I assume there must be a configuration file somewhere that refers to `chrismurphy`. I just need to find the file and update it. I've looked at all the possible configuration files according to the documentation here: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-login.1.html, but can't find the reference.

One thing I tried is to get rid of all the config files associated with `podman` by doing:

```
$ sudo apt purge podman
$ sudo apt install podman
```

, but that didn't help :(

Something else:

```
$ podman info --debug | grep chrismurphy
graphRoot: /home/chrismurphy/.local/share/containers/storage
volumePath: /home/chrismurphy/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes
```

Perhaps there are commands to change `graphRoot` and `volumePath`?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of mostly dubious research I eventually found that `/etc/subgid` had `chrismurphy` in it.

Now getting another error (which means question answered!)

```
$ podman login --get-login
Error: no registries found in registries.conf, a registry must be provided
```